# Java - Find the difference between two arrays with duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, collections

I've implemented a method for finding the difference between two unsorted arrays. Currently I have achieved getting the diff without duplicates. But how to make it take duplicates into consideration as well?
For example for the below input arrays I expect the output `[4 5 3]`:

```
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5};
int[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 3};
```

For these input arrays I expect `[7 7 9]`

```
int[] arr3 = {7, 7, 4, 9, 6};
int[] arr4 = {4, 6};
```

//

```
static ArrayList<Integer> findDifference(int[] a, int[] b) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
        { for (int i : a) add(i); }
    };
    ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
        { for (int i : b) add(i); }
    };

    if (arr1.size() > arr2.size()) {
        arr1.removeAll(arr2);
        return arr1;
    } else {
        arr2.removeAll(arr1);
        return arr2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `difference` ? Can you provide more examples?

Comment: @BlackPearl from the description it looks like they're talking about a concept similar to [relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement), but as if a set can have duplicates which are not considered actual duplicates.

Comment: If your output returns `4` (in arr1 and not in arr2) and `3` (in arr2 and not in arr1) - then you need a combination of both and `removeAll()` and a simple `return` of one array wont work -- as you are missing the data from the other

Comment: @BlackPearl in this case the difference are the numbers, without which the two arrays will contain the same elements.

Comment: I thought about using a HashMap for storing an integer value as a key and its count as a value. But no idea how I should use it afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a *count* for each value in the first array. You can use a `HashMap` to hold how many occurences you have for a specific value.

Then, for each `value` in the second array, you can decrease the already calculated count for this `value`. In the end, if the count for a specific value is `0`, this would mean that there were the same number of appearances in the both arrays. Otherwise, one of the arrays contained more occurences of `value`. The number of differences for a specific `value` would be `abs(count[value])` (as it can get negative, in the case when the second arrays contains more occurences of `value` than the first array).

This Java code illustrates the approach:

```
public List<Integer> findDiff(int[] first, int[] second) {
  Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
  for (int value : first) {
    int current = count.getOrDefault(value, 0);
    count.put(value, current + 1);
  }
  for (int value : second) {
    int current = count.getOrDefault(value, 0);
    count.put(value, current - 1);
  }
  List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : count.getEntrySet()) {
    int diff = entry.getValue();
    int times = Math.abs(diff);
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      result.add(entry.getKey());
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Clearly, we have a linear complexity for both time and memory.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not an optimal solution, but as something you can hopefully work with:

```
private static <X> Collection<X> findDiff(final Collection<X> a, final Collection<X> b) {
    // Copy the Collections so you don't modify inputs
    // and so you can safely 'remove' from them.
    final List<X> aCopy = new ArrayList<>(a);
    final List<X> bCopy = new ArrayList<>(b);

    // Remove all common elements from the copies
    // Using 'removeAll' will pull out duplicates,
    // so do this one-by-one.
    for (final X bElement : b) {
        aCopy.remove(bElement);
    }
    // Note it's important to iterate over 'a' here, not
    // aCopy since the elements of aCopy (may) have had some
    // entries 'remove'd.
    for (final X aElement : a) {
        bCopy.remove(aElement);
    }

    // Combine the two cleared out lists to find
    // the cumulative difference.
    final List<X> diff = new ArrayList<>(aCopy);
    diff.addAll(bCopy);

    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(diff);
}
```

Note, you can convert your `int[]` to a `Collection<Integer>` using something simple like:

```
IntStream.of(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note also: you can do this with fewer intermediate `Collection`s.  You only need to copy one of the input ones if you don't mind modifying the inputs.  And you don't need to combine the two into a new `diff` one.  This was just something to work with (and more explanatory).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an absolute difference between the two arrays (in this case the only different element being `4`) you could calculate the union and the intersection of the two sets.

To exclude duplicates you could also use a `Set` instead of a `List` to guarantee uniqueness. A very simple sample could be the following:

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Integer[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5};
        Integer[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 3};

        Set<Integer> diffs = findDiff(arr1, arr2);
        diffs.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static Set<Integer> findDiff(Integer[] array1, Integer[] array2) {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(array1);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(array2);
        Set<Integer> union = new HashSet<>(list1);
        union.addAll(list2);
        Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<>(list1);
        intersection.retainAll(list2);
        union.removeAll(intersection);
        return union;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But the expected output here should be `[4 5 3]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works with both exemple :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5};
    int[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 3};
    System.out.println(findDifference(arr1, arr2));
    int[] arr3 = {7, 7, 4, 9, 6};
    int[] arr4 = {4, 6};
    System.out.println(findDifference(arr3, arr4));
}
static ArrayList<Integer> findDifference(int[] a, int[] b) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Arrays.stream(a).forEach(e -> list1.add(e));
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Arrays.stream(b).forEach(e -> list2.add(e));

    ArrayList<Integer> list1Copy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2Copy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1Copy.addAll(list1);
    list2Copy.addAll(list2);

    list1.forEach(e -> list2Copy.remove(e));
    list2.forEach(e -> list1Copy.remove(e));
    list1Copy.addAll(list2Copy);
    return list1Copy;
}
```

output :

`[4, 5, 3]
 [7, 7, 9]`

The principle is to process removing operation on copy to be abble to iterate again on initial list